# Postman calls infinitely spin when calling Blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, blazor

Sending a request to the following route on postman

[image]

API controller code is as follows

[image]

Entering the route in the URL seems to hit my breakpoint fine, doing it through postman does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of turning off SSL in the project you can make Postman accept the self-signed certificate (as installed by VS).

Turn off SSL verification:

[image: Postman seetings]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen because .Net Core created an SSL cert for localhost which Postman doesn't understand. There's probably a better solution out there, but a quick fix for me was to disable SSL.

To do this, right click on your project -> Properties -> Debug tab -> Uncheck "Enable SSL"

[image]

Comment: Why don't you call the https url instead ?

Comment: @aguafrommars - probably because PostMan refuses that by default.